# Outputting required field indicator for symfony forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms

I have a few forms configured in symfony. One things I need is to have an asterisk (*) or other indicator next to fields that are required. The fields are all set to required int he form framework, and return a "this field is required" error when the form is submitted, but I want an indicator before the form is submitted.

If there any way to do this without overriding the labels for each field manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an automatic solution found in [Kris Wallsmith's blog](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/144021872/symfony-denote-required-form-fields):

lib/formatter/RequiredLabelsFormatterTable.class.php, this will add a 'required' class to the labels of required fields

```
<?php

class RequiredLabelsFormatterTable extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterTable
{
  protected
    $requiredLabelClass = 'required';

  public function generateLabel($name, $attributes = array())
  {
    // loop up to find the "required_fields" option
    $widget = $this->widgetSchema;
    do {
      $requiredFields = (array) $widget->getOption('required_fields');
    } while ($widget = $widget->getParent());

    // add a class (non-destructively) if the field is required
    if (in_array($this->widgetSchema->generateName($name), $requiredFields)) {
      $attributes['class'] = isset($attributes['class']) ?
        $attributes['class'].' '.$this->requiredLabelClass :
        $this->requiredLabelClass;
    }

    return parent::generateLabel($name, $attributes);
  }
}
```

lib/form/BaseForm.class.php, this is the common base class for all the forms in your project:

```
  protected function getRequiredFields(sfValidatorSchema $validatorSchema = null, $format = null)
  {
    if (is_null($validatorSchema)) {
      $validatorSchema = $this->validatorSchema;
    }

    if (is_null($format)) {
      $format = $this->widgetSchema->getNameFormat();
    }

    $fields = array();

    foreach ($validatorSchema->getFields() as $name => $validator) {
      $field = sprintf($format, $name);
      if ($validator instanceof sfValidatorSchema) {
        // recur
        $fields = array_merge(
          $fields,
          $this->getRequiredFields($validator, $field.'[%s]')
        );
      } else if ($validator->getOption('required')) {
        // this field is required
        $fields[] = $field;
      }
    }

    return $fields;
  }
```

add the following few lines to BaseForm as well, in the `__construct()` method:

```
$this->widgetSchema->addOption("required_fields", $this->getRequiredFields());
$this->widgetSchema->addFormFormatter('table',
  new RequiredLabelsFormatterTable($this->widgetSchema)
);
```

After all this, all your labels will have the `required` class, use whatever css you need to mark it to the user.

Comment: +1 good solution; think I saw this or similar on Kris Wallsmith's blog. Dead easy to use.  You can add the last snippet into eg `BaseFormDoctrine::__construct(...)` as well - that way all your model forms can use it automatically.

Comment: @richsage Here's [Kris Wallsmith's blog post on the subject](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/144021872/symfony-denote-required-form-fields).

Comment: That's where I got it then! I remembered finding it somewhere, I got it now from one of my old projects. Thanks for the source.

Answer (score 1):

What about the simpler solution from the original cookbook - just a few lines in twig:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels

Answer (score 0):

you can set the field's class as part of the [constructor](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormInput#method_configure) of the `sfWidget`

i.e.

```
$this->widgetSchema['form_field'] = new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('class' => 'required_field'));
```

Note: this is assuming you're not on the ancient sfForms (ala 1.0)

**UPDATE**
here is some CSS code from techchorus.net to show the required asterisk

```
.required
{
  background-image:url(/path/to/your/images/dir/required-field.png);
  background-position:top right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: class won't give me a visual indicator though, unless I make the field itself look different, but that would be weird. Also, if I wanted to add a line for each field, I would just set the label.

Comment: @MrGlass you can use css to change the appearance of over all element.  I've updated the answer with a css example

Comment: Also, for browsers (IE7 is not a browser) you can use css pseudo selector :after and property content for add asterix for required fields.
.required label :after {
    content: "*"
}
or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Javascript:

```
$('form').find('select, input, textarea').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('required') == 'required'){
        $label = $('label[for='+ $(this).attr('id') +']');

        if($label.find('.required-field').length == 0){
            $label.append('<span class="required-field">*</span>');
        }
    }
});
```